# ruby array loop always pair

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I've got the following array:

```
a = ['sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd']
```

Now I want to loop through these entries but always with two elements. I do this like the following at the moment:

```
while b = a.shift(2)
  # b is now ['sda', 'sdb'] or ['sdc', 'sdd']
end
```

This feels somehow wrong, is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to get easily to something like `[['sda', 'sdb'], ['sdc', 'sdd']]` ?

I read http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html but I didn't find something useful...

Comment: +1 for trying to read the documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You might want to look at [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) instead, which is included in `Array`.

The method you want is [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), which repeatedly yields from the enumerable the number of elements given (or less if there aren't that many at the end):

```
a = ['sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd']
a.each_slice(2) do |b|
    p b
end
```

Yields:

```bsh
$ ruby slices.rb 
["sda", "sdb"]
["sdc", "sdd"]
$
```

Comment: Okay, no comment... I checked [Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html)...

Comment: Yes, they're quite similar; note that `Enumerator` actually *includes* `Enumerable` as well; you could think of `Enumerator` like a generic interface to do enumerating things; if you call `[1, 2, 3].each` or `['sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd'].each_slice(2)`—both *without* a block—you'll get an `Enumerator` instance, which you can then further do things to.

Comment: Like `['sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd'].each_slice(2).to_a`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with strict pairs you might want to use [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) method. Here is the difference between `each_slice` and `each_cons`:

```rb
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
a.each_slice(2) { |i| p i }
# ["a", "b"]
# ["c", "d"]
# ["e"]
a.each_cons(2) { |i| p i }
# ["a", "b"]
# ["b", "c"]
# ["c", "d"]
# ["d", "e"]
```