# Loop with two elements of an array at a time

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given this array:

```
NUMERIC_FIELDS = [:a_single, :a_aggregate,
                  :field_single, :field_aggregate,
                  :line_manager_single, :line_manager_aggregate,
                  :off_single, :off_aggregate,
                  :regional_single, :regional_aggregate]
```

How can I loop over it and pass two elements of it to a method at a time? I should first pass `a_single` and `a_aggregate`, then pass `field_single` and `field_aggregate`. The method needs to loop only five times as there are five pairs of items.

```
NUMERIC_FIELDS.each do |column_name|
  are_numeric_fields_valid(column_name)
end
```

Comment: There is no hash in your code. What hash are you talking about?

Comment: sorry I'm new to ruby, I have modfiied

Comment: Now your question is a duplicate of [*ruby array loop always pair*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10816125/) and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this isn't a Hash, it's an Array of Symbols.

To get what you need you should use the [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) method

```
NUMERIC_FIELDS.each_slice(2) do |pair|
  are_numeric_fields_valid(pair[0], pair[1])
end
```

Comment: so will this pass in two at a time, how do I access each of them in my other method?

Comment: rather than referencing them by `pair[0]` and `pair[1]` why not just pass them to the block as separate variables e.g. `NUMERIC_FIELDS.each_slice(2){ |column1,column2| are_numeric_fields_valid(column1,column2) }` It adds to readability in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, that works too. I also liked passing it to the method with the splat (*) operator.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerate#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
NUMERIC_FIELDS.each_slice(2) do |column_name|
  are_numeric_fields_valid(*column_name)
end
```

The splat operator `*` is to pass two arguments instead of a single `Array`, i.e,  `are_numeric_fields_valid(:a_single, :a_aggregate)` instead of `are_numeric_fields_valid([:a_single, :a_aggregate])`.

Comment: This answer is probably the best method if you are not going to split variables in the block (as I mentioned in a comment on @nesiseka's answer) but I still think splitting the variables adds to readability

Answer (score 0):

```
NUMERIC_FIELDS.each_slice(2) do |column_name|
 # and you can grab each symbol like: column_name[0] and column_name[1]
end
```